# laravel localization with conditions

Tags: laravel, laravel-localization

Can we provide conditions to **trans** or **Lang** method other than pluralization ones, so it checks locale & the condition both to provide the required translations

> For Example: We have some translations in English for Organisation 1. And
>   different translations in English for Organisation 2. Now according to user login for organisation, the translations should be shown.
>   Remember the locale is same.

Comment: please provide an example of what you require

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not go with something like that:

```
@lang("organistation.$organisationId.text")
```

And in resources/lang/en/organisation.php:

```
<?php 
return [
    'first_organization_id' => [
        'text' => 'This text belongs to first organisation!',
        'text2' => 'Other text belongs to first organisation!'
    ],
    'second_organization_id' => [
        'text' => 'This text belongs to second organisation!',
        'text2' => 'Other text belongs to second organisation!'
    ]
];
```

etc.

Comment: Is it possible to use three arguments with @lang. I am only aware of using **group** & **key**.

Comment: @P.R. I'm not using three argument. I'm just putting this to the structure of my file. By using dot you can build your lang file as tree of arrays. So 
`"organistation.$organisationId.text"` will be looking for file `organisation.php`, then for array with key of value `$organisationId` and  then for key `'text'`. So, you can put any value under `$organisationId` and use it as key for your array.
Remember, that you need use `"` instead of `'` to replace `$organisationId`  variable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't use translations for the name of an Organisation, but just create a variable that you directly output. However you could misuse trans_choice in combination with a Constant to use that number to change the output.

```
abstract class Organisation
{
    const Organisation1 = 1;
    const Organisation2 = 2;
    const Organisation3 = 3;
    // etc
}
```

Translation

```
// en/organisations.php
'organisation' =>  '{1} Coca Cola|{2} 1 Pesi|[3, Inf] Unilever :org'    
// in your views
trans_choice('organisations.organisation', ['org' => Organisation::Organisation1 ])
```

So to recapture: the "amount" is now just a number that represents an Organisation like an Enum does.